What is Entry in FilamentPHP? What are the differences between TextColumn/TextInput and TextEntry?
I see that FilamentPHP already have TextColumn and TextInput. And it does not introduce the Entry very well as I see it here:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/infolists/entries/getting-started
What we can do in Entry (e.g. TextEntry) that we cannot do in TextColumn/TextInput?
